# OpenShift - I execute gem install rhc - successfully completed - rhc setup message command not found

Tags: java, mysql, openshift, embedded-tomcat-7, openshift-client-tools

Congrats,

I'm trying to debug an application(java tomcat7/mysql) and for that I have to install rhc, when I run gem install rhc everything proceeds normally in the installation, but when I run rhc setup message displays: command not found.

could someone help me please?

grateful

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What version of ruby are you using?  Are you using rvm or rbenv? Did you double-check there were not issues installing rhc?

Comment: thanks for the feedback .

OBS . I created my application as NOT SCALABLE .
I am using RHEL provided by OpenShift returned by uname version :
Linux ex - 2.6.32 - std - node365.prod.rhcloud.com 431.11.2.el6.bz844450.x86_64 # 1 SMP Mon Mar 31 11:32:14 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU / Linux

Comment: When I run the command: gem install rhc
================================================== =========================

If this is your first team installing the RHC tools , please run ' rhc setup'

================================================== =========================
Successfully installed rhc - 1.24.4
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rhc - 1.24.4 ...
Installing RDoc documentation for rhc - 1.24.4 ...

Comment: But when I run setup rhc
bash : rhc : command not found

The version of ruby seems to be the 193 but I can not use the command I know to check rpm -qa because the server does not allow my user if there is a suggestion to check this otherwise the server will allow me to give this tip .

If you know another way for me to debug my application , finally , accept tips .

good job and good luck ...

Comment: Are you trying to run RHC on your openshift gear?  Did you ssh into the server and try to run rhc?  You need to install & use rhc on your local machine, not on your gear.

Comment: Sorry I'm new on OpenShift: 

I have an application .war and is not maven project, to publish I followed the steps I found here in the forum: 
-I ran the git clone, git rm pom.xml after git rm -r src / 
-I copied my application .war in the webapps folder and git commit -am "message" them git push 

and is not running, so we need to view the log of this app in real time, so I'm following tutorials that show install rhc to use the tail command rhc appname. 

Can you tell me if these conditions can view the log of my app to check what can be wrong? thanks for listening and good luck

Comment: What is the name of the war file you are uploading? And what is the url you are trying to view it at?

Comment: the application name is fj21-agenda.war access by http://lojavirtual-imaster7.rhcloud.com/fj21-agenda address , published as follows using git for windows 7 - at the command prompt inside the webapps folder after remove the pom.xml file and src/ folder :
-git add fj21-agenda.war
-git commit -am "my comment"
[master 8c87f6a ] deploy fj21 - schedule
 1 file changed , 0 insertions (+) , 0 deletions (-)
 create mode 100644 webapps/fj21-agenda.war

-git push
remote: Activation status : success
remote: Deployment completed with status : success
   502e2f9..8c87f6a master -> master